# angularjs JSON object filter select option

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html-select

I'm having trouble with filtering JSON entries by defined categories with a select option element. Any help is much appreciated.

What my App should do:

1. Load JSON data from file by http.get (working)
2. The JSON data contains a job title and a job category (and other data) for each entry
3. Read each of these entries from JSON into a list-tag on html (working)
4. filter this list by a job category by a select option element (not working)

I guess the problem lies somewhere in my controller function. But I'm quite new to angularjs so I couldn't find out what the problem is... Any help is much appreciated.

first two entries of my JSON file with the tag "categories" in it:

```
   [{
    "jobtitle":"Multimedia Producer",
    "name":"A. Text",
    "shortname":"atext",
    "shortdescription":"Werbeagentur",
    "team":"XXX",
    "lookingfor":"XXX",
    "jobdescription":"XXX",
    "portfolio":"XXX",
    "contact":"XXX" ,
    "categories":"none"
   },
   {
    "jobtitle":"Kameraassistent",
    "name":"Movie & Art",
    "shortname":"movie_art",
    "shortdescription":"Corporate Movies and more...",
    "team":"XXX",
    "lookingfor":"XXX",
    "jobdescription":"XXX",
    "portfolio":"XXX",
    "contact":"XXX",
    "categories":"photography"  
   }]
```

The controller.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.jobs = data;
    $scope.catchange = 'categories'
    }); 
}]);
```

Part of the HTML-page setup with the select option element:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <span class="input">
        <select ng-model="catchange" class="cs-select cs-skin-underline">
            <option value="none">Suche nach Kategorien</option>
            <option value="photography">Fotografie</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="digital">Digital</option>
            <option value="print">Print</option>
            <option value="consulting">Beratung</option>
            <option value="advertising">Werbung</option>
            <option value="socialmedia">Social Media</option>
            <option value="strategy">Strategie</option>
            <option value="conception">Konzeption</option>
            <option value="film">Film</option>
            <option value="tv">TV</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="searchlisting" ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul class="portfolio-grid">    
        <li class="grid-item" ng-repeat="item in jobs | filter: catchange" data-jkit="[show:delay=300;speed=500;animation=fade]">
            <img ng-src="img/searchlist/{{item.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="Photo of {{item.name}}">
            <a class="ajax-link" href="single.html">  
                <div class="grid-hover">
                    <h1>{{item.jobtitle}}</h1>
                    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                </div>
            </a>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand what this line is supposed to represent?  `$scope.catchange = 'categories'`.  you are essentially setting your filter to a string `'categories'`, which isn't even a valid option in the select list.

Comment: Yes I think thats the problem. Thank you Claies. How can I fix this, that it takes the corresponding entry? Sorry - I'm new to angular...

Comment: What it supposed to do: User selects on the select list one of the entries (categories) and angular will then only show the corresponding entries (=categories-tag) from the JSON file.
guidokoch.ch/jobplattform/jobsuche.html

Comment: ok, let's break down what it is you are trying to do a bit here.  your service is fetching a list of jobs, and you want to filter them based on the dropdown.  why would you even need to set the value of the dropdown to anything the moment you receive your data?

Comment: Ok, after reloading my browser, I could use the dropdown; however checking the console, your service appears to be throwing a 404 fetching your data, and doesn't have anything to filter.

Comment: Ok there was my mistake. So I can clear this line, if I get what you are saying: $scope.catchange = 'categories'

Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you Claies. The 404 war caused by a missing icon... I'm somehow getting to the problem - I'm now working with the solution from Georgette (see below). Its not working properly yet, but I hope to get it fixed. Anyway many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catchange will be a string, and when you filter, you are iterating over each object that is a job. So really, you need to be comparing each job.categories against catchange model.

Therefore, when you are doing filter:catchange, you are comparing each job object against the selected string in catchange, where you need to be comparing job.categories to catchange. You can tell angular what to track an iterator by to make sure it is comparing, or you can do the following:

Write a filter function that returns a boolean. This is just one way

this will be the filter in the view, angular passes each job as a param

```
filter: filterCategory
```

This will be a function in your controller that needs to compare the incoming job category with the categories that need to be filtered out. Just have it return a boolean.

```
$scope.filterCategory = function(job){
    return $scope.catchange.filter(category){
      job.categories === category
    }
}
```

edit: Above assumes multi-select options, where catchange is an array of selected options stored via string. If it only ever going to be a single category select then

```
$scope.filterCategory = function(job){
    if($scope.catchange){
        return job.categories === $scope.catchange
    } 
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Georgette for answering and your explanation. I'm getting a sense of what I'm doing wrong...
Somehow, your notation gives me a syntax error - so my controller is now looking like this:
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
 
 $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
  $scope.jobs = data;
  
  $scope.filterCategory = (function(job){
     return job.categories === catchange
     }); 
     });   
     }]);

Comment: hard to read that, but I did have a syntax error ( used : instead of = when declaring function). See above fix.

Comment: Thank you for the fix! I'm not getting to solve the problem though - can I ask you for help again?

I stripped all the css and other js away from the page to see if something interferes the app. But it doesn't. So I uploaded the this stripped version on my server here: [link](http://guidokoch.ch/jobplattform/test-ngoptions.html)

Can you take a look at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok the the console in my browser says that 'catchange' isn't defined. I guess I need to define it in the controller - but how?

Comment: Just initialize it to empty string:  $scope.catchange = ''; Then when a user actually selects an option in the dropdown, $scope.catchange will capture the value and then angular will detect the model change and refilter.

Comment: Also, you have to return true in the filter function when catchange is not set yet by the user, or it will filter out everything by default (as job.categories === catchange  will never be true )

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you soo much Georgette!! :) Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the property name that you want filter:

```
<li class="grid-item" ng-repeat="item in jobs | filter: {categories: catchange}" data-jkit="[show:delay=300;speed=500;animation=fade]">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it, but it didn't help.

Link to the full page: http://www.guidokoch.ch/jobplattform/jobsuche.html